# Listbox in other Listbox, Itemsource, Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I would like to know How to refresh our ListBox item. 
I tried OnPropertyChanged method, ObservableCollection, but it didn't work. I tried set again the itemsource property, so that worked, but now I have got 2 ListBox and now it's complicated. It's a wp7 project there is the main interface. You can see I have 2 listbox

```
 <ListBox Name="lsbNameDays" ItemsSource="ComplexNameDays">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameDay.Name}" FontSize="50"/>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="ComplexNameDays.FacebookFriends" x:Name="asdf">
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lastname}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

there is the properties:

```
 List<SelectedNameDays> complexNameDays;

      public List<SelectedNameDays> ComplexNameDays
            {
                get { return complexNameDays; }
                set 
                { 
                    complexNameDays = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ComplexNameDays");
                }


               }

     public class SelectedNameDays : Notifier
        {
            NameDay _nameday;

            public NameDay NameDay
            {
                get { return _nameday; }
                set { _nameday = value; OnPropertyChanged("NameDay"); }
            }


            public List<FacebookFriend> FacebookFriends { get; set; }

            public SelectedNameDays()
            {
                _nameday = new NameDay();
            }
        }

    public class FacebookFriend
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Firstname { get; set; }
            public string Lastname { get; set; }
            public string Birthday { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public Uri Picture { get; set; }
        }
```

The begining of the code is correct, that works, because when the Constructor set the datas I set retry the itemsource of lbsNameDays, but i cant find the  "asdf" listbox, i can't set their datas again.

so the 2 main question are that.
 1. how can i fire the property changed if that, and the observable collecton doesn't works.
 2. how can I use asdf listbox in the datatemplate

thank the answer, and I sorry my grammer mistakes

Comment: `FacebookFriend` also needs to inherit from `Notify` (call `OnPropertyChanged` in every property of the class)... this way changes in `FacebookFriend` will also change in UI

Comment: I think ItemsSource of "asdf" ListBox should be <ListBox ItemsSource="FacebookFriends" x:Name="asdf">

Answer (score 1):

Your Bindings won't work, because you dont use the right syntax:

```
   ItemsSource="ComplexNameDays"
```

should be

```
   ItemsSource="{Binding ComplexNameDays}"
```

The second binding is also wrong:

```
   ItemsSource="ComplexNameDays.FacebookFriends"
```

Comment: +1 You should use data binding for enabling change notification